# How can I add case insensitivity in Duckling software

Tags: haskell, duckling

I am using Duckling software.
In the FR Rules file:

```
ruleDemain :: Rule
ruleDemain = Rule
  { name = "demain"
  , pattern =
     [ regex "(le len)?demain"
     ]
  , prod = \_ -> tt $ cycleNth TG.Day 1
  }
```

I want the software to be able to interpret **demain** and **Demain** as the same word.
I am looking for a global solution for all the rules.

Comment: I don't really know anything about the library, so there may be a More Official Way, but... perhaps changing that to `"(le len)?[Dd]emain"` is good enough for you?

Comment: Yes that's useful for one rule but am looking for a global way to solve this for all rules.

Answer (score 2):

According to that tool's [readme](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/duckling-0.2.0.0#readme), it uses PCRE for its regexes. So you should be able to use (?i) for case-insensitive mode:

```
ruleDemain :: Rule
ruleDemain = Rule
  { name = "demain"
  , pattern =
     [ regex "(?i)(le len)?demain"
     ]
  , prod = \_ -> tt $ cycleNth TG.Day 1
  }
```